# Creating SubDomain for an account on registration

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, deployment, subdomain

I am working on a ASP.NET app hosted on IIS.

I want to give a separate sub-domain (username.abc.com) or a directory (abc.com/username) access to different users upon registration.

I am not getting enough leads to do this with IIS. I got few links but those describe the solution in Apache.

Can any one please give me some leads to do this with ASP.NET/IIS programmatically?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have subdomains point to another server or another subfolder under the same server, with a different set of files including a web.config. It could be a totally separate project. You could have a landing page or site, and upon authentication, based on the user privileges or whatever, you can redirect him to the corresponding site/subdomain.

But you probably should not try to create them on the fly as it is unnecessary. There has to be a better model. I'm not sure if this is what you are asking but the question is not very clear.

UPDATE: Based on some input from asker, I believe this is related to url rewriting. See comments for details.

Comment: umm. Okay! What I want is, to give a different dashboard url to every user on registration. like username.abc.com OR abc.com/username By what you said, do you mean creating same code for every user in different sub domain or different directory? I want something like how facebook does for every user - facebook.com/username

Comment: This is called url rewriting. Check this out, http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx. Does that work for you? You basically will have to write an httpmodule that receives request and processes it appropriately. It will be better to go with domain.com/username.